# selecting row with many child rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am hoping I can make myself understood enough! I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calendar_date,'%W %D, %M, %Y') AS calendar_date,calendar_entry_title,calendar_entry_teaser
        FROM calendar_month
        LEFT JOIN calendar_entry ON calendar_entry.calendar_id = calendar_month.calendar_id
        ORDER BY calendar_date
```

Here are the table detail I am dealing with.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calendar_entry` (
  `calendar_entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `calendar_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calendar_entry_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `calendar_entry_teaser` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `calendar_entry_text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`calendar_entry_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `calendar_entry`
--

INSERT INTO `calendar_entry` (`calendar_entry_id`, `calendar_id`, `school_id`, `calendar_entry_title`, `calendar_entry_teaser`, `calendar_entry_text`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'School Event 1', 'School event information 1', 'This would be the full body of the text that would show on the full page for this given entry'),
(2, 1, 1, 'School Event 2', 'School event information 2', 'This would be the full body of the text that would show on the full page for this given entry');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calendar_month` (
  `calendar_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calendar_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`calendar_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `calendar_month`
--

INSERT INTO `calendar_month` (`calendar_id`, `school_id`, `calendar_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2012-08-11'),
(2, 1, '2012-08-12');
```

The problem I have is, there are only 2 rows in the calendar_month table. One of these rows has 2 rows related to it in the month_entry table. When I run the query that I have it will display 3 rows. what I need it to do is only show 2 rows, the month that has two rows I need to be displayed as one row. Can this be done with how I have set it up?

Thanks

result -

```
Saturday 11th, August, 2012     School Event 1  School event information 1
Saturday 11th, August, 2012     School Event 2  School event information 2
Sunday 12th, August, 2012   NULL    NULL
```

What I actually want -

```
Saturday 11th, August, 2012     School Event 1  School event information 1 School Event 2   School event information 2
Sunday 12th, August, 2012   NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Have you tried Select Distinct ?

Comment: No, it is still giving me the 3 rows of data :(

Comment: You could remove the JOIN and use a subquery but it can be resource-intensive, so i'd advise you to stick to the JOIN and rather fix that when you loop through your results in php (i assume you use php).

Comment: can you show the 3 rows and point out the 2 that you want ?

Comment: I am actually echo'ng the data to JSON

Comment: I have edited question with actual rows + wanted rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calendar_date,'%W %D, %M, %Y') AS calendar_date, TMP.var1
FROM calendar_month
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(calendar_entry_title, ' ',calendar_entry_teaser) AS var1, calendar_id
         FROM calendar_entry
     GROUP BY calendar_id) AS TMP ON TMP.calendar_id = calendar_month.calendar_id
ORDER BY calendar_date
```

Comment: "Do not scale too fast" - it's a query without external parameters. Looks like perfect candidate for caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that kind of result in mysql only, or using 2 subquery for each row, which will sooner or later crash your server. Rather, use php to sort through the result and store in which calendar_entry_title you are.
example:

```
$query =" SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calendar_date,'%W %D, %M, %Y') AS calendar_date,
calendar_entry_title,
calendar_entry_teaser
        FROM calendar_month
        LEFT JOIN calendar_entry ON calendar_entry.calendar_id = calendar_month.calendar_id
        ORDER BY calendar_date, calendar_entry_title";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$events = array();
foreach($result as $r){
     $events[$r['calendar_date']][] = $r;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($events);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: for which line? i kind of skipped the mysql part, i thought you'd got that part working.